# Using Phonegap and Disqus javascript SDK issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, disqus

I am using Phonegap and Disqus javascript SDK and the following error message occurs:

"Unable to post message to http://disqus.com. Recipient has origin file://."

Any help will be very much appreciated. I would like a solution to work on iOS + Android.

Cordova/PhoneGap 1.9

DISQUS CODE:

```
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'phonegap-app'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

Comment: Just added the disqus code above...thanks

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this please?

Comment: Any way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you're accessing the page via a file:// URL. You can fix this by serving the page up from a local webserver.